# Why are we not being able to calculate percentage?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Question:
"What is the percentage change in the result when we add $50$ to a certain number $x$, instead of subtracting $50$ from the same number $x$?"

Doubt:
In the previous problem that I solved, the same question was modified as multiplied by $10$ instead of being divided, and we genuinely arrived at the correct answer. Here, the answer key reads "cannot be determined". If so, where did I go wrong? Any form of assistance is most welcome.

Comment: What percent changes do you get when $x = 0$?  How about when $x = 100$?  Why would there be a single answer for all $x$s?

Comment: Unable to follow this. Please elaborate slightly.

Comment: What is the percentage change in the result when we add 50 to 0, instead of subtracting 50 from the same number, 0?  What is the percentage change in the result when we add 50 to 100, instead of subtracting 50 from the same number, 100?

Comment: Still not able to get how would that impact the result?

Comment: Literally:  Answer the question.  What is the percentage change in the result when we add 50 to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the percentage change (in decimal form) from starting with $x$ and ending with $y$ is

$$\frac {y-x}x$$

So, for example, the percentage change from $10$ to $15$ is

$$\frac {15-10}{10}=0.5=50\text{%}$$

Now, the question is what is the percentage change if we added $50$ to some number $x$, instead of subtracting $50$ from $x$. We are starting with $x-50$ and ending with $x+50$. So, our percentage change is

$$\frac {(x+50)-(x-50)}{x-50}=\frac {100}{x-50}$$

Notice that the answer depends on what $x$ is, so there is no single answer. For example, if $x=100$, then the percentage change would be $100/50=2=200\text{%}$. If $x=150$, then the percentage change would be $100/100=1=100\text{%}$.